# Extract data from cell array and include index of cell for identification

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a `69x1`cell array. Each row contains 3 columns of double but with variable numbers of rows.

In each row there are, for example;

4x3 double 
13x3 double 
... etc.

I extract all the data from the cell array into one matrix using;

```
result = vertcat(data{:})
```

What I would like to do is to give them an identify based on which cell they are extracted from in the data cell array.  For example, the 4 rows extracted from the 1st row in the data cell array would have 1 in front of them...so i would get something like;

```
1,x,y,z
1,x,y,z
1,x,y,z
1,x,y,z (as row 1 in data has 4 rows)
2,x,y,z
2,x,y,z (for the 13 rows)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way:

```
data = { rand(2,3);
         rand(5,3) }

%// create identity vector
out1 = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x) x.*ones(1,size(data{x},1)), 1:numel(data),'uni',0)).' %'
%// convert data from cell to double matrix
out2 = cell2mat(data)

%// concatenate output
out = [ out1 , out2 ]
```

or directly

```
out = cell2mat([arrayfun(@(x)x.*ones(1,size(data{x},1)).',1:numel(data),'uni',0).',data])
```

---

**or a little more fancy and a bit less costly** (untested):

```
%// create identity vector
A(cumsum([1; cellfun(@(x) size(x,1),data)])) = 1

%// concatenate output
out = [cumsum(A(1:end-1)).' cell2mat(data)]
```

gives:

```
data = 
    [2x3 double]
    [5x3 double]


out =
            1      0.88441     0.018613      0.43851
            1      0.72086      0.67478      0.43782
            2      0.11704      0.37569      0.51537
            2      0.81468      0.54655      0.65753
            2      0.32486      0.56192      0.95092
            2      0.24623      0.39582      0.72235
            2      0.34271      0.39813      0.40008
```

Comment: Perfect! @thewatwewalk 

I just tested your "untested" method, and it works perfectly too.

Comment: @user3644826 the *"untested"* comment was regarding the *"a bit less costly"* statement :)